# Backup program for encrypted data for linux

Tags: linux, backup, encryption

I was sent over here by the *super user* guys, because my question is better suited here.

I have that policy that I leave no data unencrypted, so I am looking for a program or suite of scripts that lets me backup directly into an encrypted container. To be useful it should do the following:

- Automated backup to a local or/and remote encrypted target storage
- Incremental backup
- Automated mounting/unmounting of said storage or provide hooks to insert instructions to do so
- Automatic rotation, so I can store monthly backups of site
- Run on *linux* and has to be maintained
- Prompt the user to attach the storage device if it is missing
- Must not dependent on a service provider

Bonus points if:

- it has a GUI for status information and simple operation like postpone/pause
- it integrates with PAM/keyrings so the user does not need to provide the password every time the backup starts
- it is *open source* or open source friendly

I started to hack something together myself but then this feeling crept up on me that I am reinventing the wheel and I am just too stupid to find the proper solution. Does anyone have a recommendation?

What I already looked at:

- fwbackup -> no encryption
- simple backup solution -> no encryption
- bacula -> has encryption but way too complicated for only 5 machines

Thank you for all the tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not 100% sure if it hits all your requirement but [**Déjà Dup**](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup) is definitively worth a look:

- it uses duplicity/rsync as backend
- use local, external or network-storage (ssh, ftp, WebDAV, smb, etc.)
- scheduled backups (more flexible settings via dconf/gsettings)
- optional encryption via symmetric gpg and integrates with keyring
- notifies via libnotify when a backup is pending but target is missing
- it works unattached but integrates with several DE-panels for information, status, pause, stop/skip, etc.

`deja-dup` is for sure open source and therefor in most major distributions repositories.

Comment: uuuh that looks tasty :-) I'll check that out. I let you know.

Comment: Just checked it out. I like the GUI interface, it is simple enough so a user can pause it when it is causing inconvenience. I also looked up duplicity. I still need to figure out scheduling because the GUI options are rather limited in this regard. But I am confident that I can work this out. In the worst case i need a crone job that does the monthly rotation. Thank you very much for this, it might save me a whole world of trouble. I also like that is GTK3 and it is in the fedora main repo :-)

Comment: @paradoxon: as said, have a look with the `dconf-editor` at the schema *org.gnome.DejaDup* for more settings, or use `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.DejaDup` in the terminal for a first impression.

Comment: @paradoxon: by the way... what do you want to achieve with *"monthly rotation"*? - keep in mind the backups are incremental; so you need all the files for restoring!

Comment: Thx for the extra hints :-) I think I am good from here. I borrowed the term from log management. Where you stop writing to a file, rename and compress it and start a new one. I'd like to do do a similar thing with my backups. This way I only have the current month on site can bring the rest to a safe location of site.